# Removing a player's leaderstats if they click a gui on roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

Some simple code

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Up:connect(function()
    ????.leaderstats.lvl.Value = 0
    ????.leaderstats.xp.Value = 0
    ????.leaderstats.gold.Value = 0
```

It's not even working. So the player clicks the gui, but how can it reset the players leaderstats, specifically lvl, xp, and gold, I run a fairly popular roblox rpg game with about 400 people right now and this would be an immense help.

Comment: Try having your callback take a parameter. Maybe the mousebutton1up event passes the parent to it?

Comment: where is the player defined? global? in script?

Comment: it's inside a script.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the following code in a **LocalScript** inside your button.

```
    Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer --Only works inside a localscript, replace with the line below it if you need it as a Script.
    -- Player=script.Parent while (not Player:IsA("Player")) do Player = Player.Parent end

    script.Parent.MouseButton1Up:connect(function()
        local index, stat
        for index, stat in pairs(Player.leaderstats:GetChildren()) do
            stat.Value = 0
        end
    end)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be in a LocalScript, so you can just use the LocalPlayer variable to get the leaderstats and set them.